# Is there any way to download Text Search to localhost dev server?

Tags: google-app-engine

Now on Google App Engine you can download kinds to localhost dev server via appcfg command, is there any way to download Text Search indexes to localhost dev server for local test and debug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment, sorry. It wouldn't be too hard to write an app that does this, but we don't have a tool for it yet.

Comment: your toolbelt lacks some very important tools